# How does Flutter project integrate Android native

Tags: android, flutter, openvidu

My flutter project now needs to integrate the Android native openvidu live interaction function, but I can only find the integrated flutter in the native project in the official document. What should I do

Comment: [this video will help you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UftAAKSuVs&ab_channel=JohannesMilke)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a flutter plugin to communicate from flutter to android native. You can check this doc
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages